# Is it possible to have row headers in an XSL-FO table?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am not sure if my title has asked this correctly, so let me try to explain in case I haven't. The first row of the table is a header-row, no issues with making that happen. The first column, from the second row onward is effectively a header-column.

Some cells in this column span multiple rows, and some times this column will span multiple pages. I am looking for a way to repeat the text held in the cell should the column span a page break. Similar to how the header row repeats. I have no example to share, as I am unsure where I should even begin, or as my question title states, if this is even possible.

I am using FOP 2.0. Hope someone may have an idea, or can point me in a direction of how to get started.

Comment: Its a great question ... what do you wish to appear in the document should your header line have 10 lines of text and you cells have one?

Answer (score 1):

It's not in XSL 1.1, but was in the requirements for XSL 2.0: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#N66269

It's also not among the FOP extensions at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/extensions.html

It is, however, supported by AH Formatter: http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-ext.html#axf.table-cell-repeated-marker

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had initially misread your second statement and omitted the 'not'. Got my hopes up. Is there any indication as to when the XSL FO 2.0 will move from a being a draft? But I also assume that even though that were to happen, no guarantee that FOP will support it initially either.